# Javascript Not Updating Database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a Edit Profile, for the user's profile. Well, The Javascript seems to be only getting the value of the Age's Form. The PHP File is getting the Age, but no others and it's not updating the database.

Javascript:

```
function UpdateProfile() {
var newage = $("#NewAge").val();
var newimage = $("#NewImage").val();    
var newbio = $("#NewBio").val();    
var dataString = 'newage=' + newage || 'newimage=' + newimage || 'newbio=' + newbio;    
if (newbio.length , newage.length , newimage.length == 0) {
    $('#Required').fadeIn(300);
    $('#Mask').fadeIn(300);     
} else {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_profile.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (UpdateProfile) {
            $('#EditInfo').hide();
            $("#UpdatedProfile").html(UpdateProfile);
            $("#UpdatedProfile").fadeIn('slow');
            $("#Age").html('Age: ' + newage);
            $('#Image').html('<img src="' + newimage +'" width="150" height="100" />');                                             
        }
    });
   }
}
```

Here's The update_profile.php File:

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<?php include 'connect.php' ?>     
      <?php
        $newimage = $_POST['newimage'];
        $newbio = $_POST['newabout'];
        $newage = $_POST['newage'];         
            $update = "UPDATE members SET bio=(".$newbio.") age=(".$newage.") image=(".$newimage.") WHERE id='".$id."'";
            $res = mysql_query($update);
            echo 'Success: Profile Updated!<br />';
            echo $update . '<br />';
      ?>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="NewAge" value="<?php echo $age ?>" maxlength="2" />
<input type="text" id="NewImage" value="<?php echo $image ?>" maxlength="500" />
<textarea id="NewBio" style="width: 500; max-width: 500; height: 100; max-height: 150;"><?php echo $bio ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Update Profile" onClick="UpdateProfile()" />
```

The Code The Update outputs is this:

```
Success: Profile Updated!
UPDATE members SET bio=() age=(18) image=() WHERE id='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: { newimage: newimage,
            newage: newage,
            newbio: newbio }
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this line:

```
 $newbio = $_POST['newabout'];
```

to

```
 $newbio = $_POST['newbio'];
```

And it should work.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to change that earlier, But Nope, still outputting This..
    UPDATE members SET bio=() age=(18) image=() WHERE id='1'

Comment: So Can You Think of any other ideas?